# How to handle Notification on app open in Ionic 3 & Cordova OneSignal Plugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic3, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal to send an receive notification in Ionic 3 APP.

My Code is (Working Perfectly)

```
this.oneSignal.startInit(Config.oneSignal.appId, Config.oneSignal.firebaseSenderId);
    this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None);
    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe((data: any) => {
      const attempt = data.payload.additionalData.attempt;
      if (data.isAppInFocus) {
        this.presentModalDefense(attempt);
        this.oneSignal.cancelNotification(data.androidNotificationId);
      } else {
        this.badge.increase(1).then(data => {
          console.log(data);
        });
      }

    });

    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((data: any) => {
      const attempt = data.notification.payload.additionalData.attempt;
      if (!data.isAppInFocus) {
        this.attemptProvider.howLongTimeAgo(attempt.id).subscribe((timeago: any) => {
          let config = this.auth.getConfig();
          if (timeago.seconds >= config["SPEED_TO_ROB"].value) {
            this.presentModalUnsuccessfulDefense(attempt);
          } else {
            this.presentModalDefense(attempt, timeago.seconds);
          }
        }, err => {

        });
      }
    });
    this.oneSignal.endInit();
```

My Problem is

I want to call `this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened()` (for all pending notifications which are not yet handled)

1. If user Tap on the APP Icon *(Looking for solution in this case)*
2. If user Tap on the notification *(This case working)*

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Don't rely on notifications. Delivery is not guaranteed. I'm not saying don't use them but make sure that your app works properly without them.

Comment: Do you have any answer for this?